# C#/Ajax – Problemas al pasar modelo con listas a un controlador

Tags: javascript, c#, ajax

Buen día a todos, les comento que estoy tratando de capturar data de un método JavaScript con ajax, el tema es que al pasarlo a mi controlador con el formato de model que tengo, este no obtiene toda la información enviada a pesar de que la información coincide con los nombres de los modelos, esta información solo no la captura cuando el modelo tiene que ver con una lista, colocare mi JavaScript, controlador y método.

Controlador:

```
[HttpPost]
    public JsonResult pruebaArticulo(List<ArticuloModel> articuloLista)
    {
        return Json(new { data = "" }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);

    }
```

Modelo:

```
public class ArticuloModel
{
    public string ID_ARTICULO { get; set; } = "";
    public string TIPO_ARTICULO { get; set; } = "";
    public List<ArticuloPrincipal> ARTICULOS_PRINCIPALES { get; set; }
    public List<ArticuloSecundario> ARTICULO_SECUNDARIO { get; set; }
    public string FECHA_CREACION { get; set; } = Convert.ToString(DateTime.Now);
    public string FECHA_MODIFICACION { get; set; } = "";
    public string USUARIO_CREACION { get; set; } = "SISTEMA";
    public string USUARIO_MODIFICACION { get; set; } = "";
    public string ACTIVACION { get; set; } = "S";

}

public class ArticuloPrincipal
{
    public string ARTICULO_ID { get; set; } = "";
    public string NOMBRE_ARTICULO { get; set; } = "";
    public string DETALLE_ARTICULO { get; set; } = "";
}



public class ArticuloSecundario
{
    public string ARTICULO_SECUNDARIO_ID { get; set; } = "";
    public string NOMBRE_ARTICULO_SECUNDARIO { get; set; } = "";
    public string DETALLE_ARTICULO_SECUNDARIO { get; set; } = "";
    public List<ArticuloComplemento> ARTICULO_COMPLEMENTO { get; set; }
}

public class ArticuloComplemento
{
    public string COMPLEMENTO_ARTICULO_ID { get; set; } = "";
    public string NOMBRE_ARTICULO_COMPLEMENTO { get; set; } = "";
    public string DETALLE_ARTICULO_COMPLEMENTO { get; set; } = "";
    public List<ArticuloAuxiliar> ARTICULO_AUXILIAR { get; set; }
}


public class ArticuloAuxiliar
{
    public string AUXILIAR_COMPLEMENTO_ID { get; set; } = "";
    public string NOMBRE_ARTICULO_AUXILIAR { get; set; } = "";
    public string DETALLE_ARTICULO_AUXILIAR { get; set; } = "";
}
```

Javascript:

```
$("#btnGrabarArticulo").click(function () {

var textoHtml = $('#summernote').summernote('code');

var TIPO_ARTICULO = $("#cmbTipoArticulo").val();

var NOMBRE_ARTICULO = "articulo_principal_nombre";
var DETALLE_ARTICULO = textoHtml;

var NOMBRE_ARTICULO_SECUNDARIO = "articulo_secundario_nombre";
var DETALLE_ARTICULO_SECUNDARIO = textoHtml;

var NOMBRE_ARTICULO_COMPLEMENTO = "complementario_nombre";
var DETALLE_ARTICULO_COMPLEMENTO = textoHtml;

var NOMBRE_ARTICULO_AUXILIAR = "auxiliar_nombre";
var DETALLE_ARTICULO_AUXILIAR = textoHtml;

var valueCampos = new Array();

var ARTICULO_AUXILIAR = { NOMBRE_ARTICULO_AUXILIAR, DETALLE_ARTICULO_AUXILIAR };
var ARTICULO_COMPLEMENTO = { NOMBRE_ARTICULO_COMPLEMENTO, DETALLE_ARTICULO_COMPLEMENTO, ARTICULO_AUXILIAR };
var ARTICULO_SECUNDARIO = { NOMBRE_ARTICULO_SECUNDARIO, DETALLE_ARTICULO_SECUNDARIO, ARTICULO_COMPLEMENTO };
var ARTICULOS_PRINCIPALES = { NOMBRE_ARTICULO, DETALLE_ARTICULO };
var articulo = { TIPO_ARTICULO, ARTICULOS_PRINCIPALES, ARTICULO_SECUNDARIO };

valueCampos.push(articulo);
var postData = { articuloLista: valueCampos };

$.ajax(
    {
        url: '/Admin/pruebaArticulo',
        data: JSON.stringify(postData), 
        contentType: 'application/json',
        dataType: 'json',
        type: 'POST',
        success: function (data) {
            console.log(data);
        }, error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, error) {
            console.log("ERROR");
        }
    });
```

});

Si revisamos la data enviada por mi ajax, muestra que captura y envía todo de forma correcta (según entiendo).

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
Pero al llegar a mi controlador este no obtiene la información correspondiente a los List
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Por lo que quería solicitar su ayuda, ya que no se si estoy fallando en la forma de envió/captura o me falta algo.
Desde ya muchas gracias.

Comment: Es que... `JSON.stringify(postData)` Está enviando una cadena de texto, no una lista...

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow en español! Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!